# How to create a fake device file that accepts input from a C++ program?

Tags: c++, lua, integration-testing, embedded-linux

I work on embedded linux. I want to mocks Linux devices for creating integration tests.
I need to send input from fake devices. I will integrate in C++ code.
Actually if I do this, I will write Integration Test with Lua.
Would you like recommend any solution about mock input device?

**I used umockdev. But I have a problem about record device. I didn't record anything into ioctl file.**

************************** Touchpad ****************************

```
sudo umockdev-record /dev/input/event5 > mouse.umockdev

sudo umockdev-record -i /dev/input/event5=mouse.ioctl -e /dev/input/event5=mouse.events -- evtest /dev/input/event5

umockdev-run -d mouse.umockdev -i /dev/input/event5=mouse.ioctl -e /dev/input/event5=mouse.events -- evtest /dev/input/event5
```

After this step I got following error message Step: "umockdev-run -d

> event-kbd.umockdev -i /dev/input/event10=event-kbd.ioctl -e
>   /dev/input/event10=event-kbd.events -- evtest /dev/input/event10" 
>   "ERROR: libumockdev-preload: failed to load ioctl record file for
>   /dev/input/event10: empty or invalid format"

I didn't get any error during installation. Probably umockdev didn't record to "*.ioctl" file  anything which didn't contain anything.

> (Only contain this one: "@DEV /dev/input/event10" )

Comment: So, to clarify, Lua is just what you plan to use for testing, but not what you want to use to mock the device, right?

Comment: I will mock devices, send mocked input to C++ code. And I will use mocked-input in C++ code , use with Lua. (only integration tests)
Actually, I want to write blackbox test (integration test). I work on AGL. 
Example above (mouse-related ) is for your umockdev testing.  So, I will mock input device. Such as, volume change button, forward-backforward button.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to answer your question. Exactly yes :) 
Do you want to recommend anything else?